# Opening a child dialog that overrides parent dialog dimension

Tags: android, dialog

I want to create a dialog from another dialog's button click. I want the second dialog to occupy the whole screen, but the parent dialog itself is small. So, the second one ends up with the size of parent dialog.

Is there any way to achieve this? Making the child dialog bigger than the parent dialog?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured out a way. Trick is to not use a child dialog in the first place. Instead do something like the following.

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child,null);
parentDialog.setContentView(v); //Note that the parent dialog had a content view of its own
```

If anyone finds a better alternative please post. Till then I'll leave it here.